# Docker container issues (start/stop and WebAPI access)

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-web-api, docker-for-windows

Colleagues,
I'm having hard times to run a Docker image I've created. The application I'm trying to containerize is a simple Windows Service that exposes WebAPI (REST) via certain port. It works just fine locally but not in the container. I'm facing two following issues:

- When I run container it start and in approx. 20 sec stops. I figured it can be due to the 'nature' of a container (if it's still the case), i.e. **if it doesn't have active processes running, it stops automatically**. Is it right? I found a nice PS script that does the job. i.e. verifies if the service is running and it runs until the service runs. The only problem, I can't install it to the image. The command: `CMD ["powershell wait-service.ps1 -ServiceName SelfHostService"]` doesn't work because Docker doesn't like parameters I'm trying to submit. Any ideas how to circumvent this issue?
- Another problem, when the service runs for a very short period of time, it turned out I can't access it, i.e. once container is up and running I submit the following request from the Postman 'localhost:8080/api/welcome/' and it returns "**HTTP Error 403. The request URL is forbidden**" whereas locally it works fine. Is there any gotchas concerning hosting such things in the container?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, docker container will exit when your foreground process exits. If it doesn't run, docker thinks the application is stopped and it shuts down the container.

You are not passing arguments to the `CMD` command correctly, for more see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd). Some examples from the docs

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (preferred form)
CMD ["param1","param2"] (ad default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
CMD  command param1 param2 (shell form)
```

I think that you're trying to access `localhost:8080/api/welcome` from your host instead from the container. You can only access `localhost` from inside your container. You can do that by running your container in interactive mode (using the `-it` flags) and then accessing `localhost`.
If you want to access your container from your host you need to `EXPOSE` the port `8080` in your `docker image` and then `publish port 8080`. With that you can access your api using `http://your_hostname:8080/api/welcome` (persuming you publish port 8080 on 8080 e.g. using flag `-p 8080:8080`)

Comment: I'm exposing the port and publishing it as well but still, it doesn't work. In the Dockerfile I use 'EXPOSE 8080' command to expose the port and after successful build I run the container with the following command: docker run --name apiservice -d -p 8080:8080 apiservice

Comment: Did you change your "CMD" command? Please post a minimal example of your code that reproduces your error.
Can you please explain in a bit more detail, what "doesn't work"? Are you still getting a 503 error? How are you trying to access your api?